# Changing the size of popup.html in a google-chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome-extension with a popup.html file that creates a form that is too big. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" id="mytable">

<tbody><tr><td>Song:</td> <td><input type="text" name="song" size="30" /> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Artist:</td> <td><input type="text" name="artist" size="30" /> </td></tr>
</tbody></table>

<input onclick="sendRequest()" type="button" name="method" value="Search" height="10"/>
<input onclick="help()" type="button" name="method" value="Help" height="10"/>

</body>
</html>
```

The form created by this code extends about 25 pixels lower after the buttons end. What is causing this?

EDIT: I realized that this might be caused by a minimum size issue that chrome may have. Is there a way to change the minimum size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting bug, seems like it calculates popup height incorrectly if table contains input elements (without them looks fine). You can try to file a bug report to http://crbug.com

Meanwhile adding `style="float:left;"` to the table seems to fix the problem.

(you are also closing body tag twice)